# WPF Image source not loaded from stream

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, image-processing

I've got WCF service to catch webcam images and send to client, it works great in my WinForms app. I decided to crate WPF client app.

**I've got code:**

```
void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       counter++;
       try
       {
            Stream imageStream = client.GetImage();
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                imageStream.CopyTo(stream);
                int size = (int)stream.Length;
                cam_img.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(stream,
                                                  BitmapCreateOptions.None,
                                                  BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(counter);
       }
       catch (System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException ex)
       {
            if (ex.InnerException is System.ServiceModel.QuotaExceededException)
            {

            }
            else
            { 
                throw ex;
            }

       }
       catch (System.Exception ex)
       {

       }
}
```

cam_img is a Image Control. In debugger mode i see that stream contains data, but `cam_img.source` is `null` in every tick event.

Next question is, do i have to implement propertychanged event to make dynamic binding with image? Or assign to `cam_img.source` in each timer tick is enough to see dynamic changing on control?

Comment: sorry, cam_img.source is null in every tick event. it seems like something is wrong with bitmapfram.create, because stream contains data

Comment: @user3197850 please answer the questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question 2:

No, you **don't** need the `PropertyChanged`, you can just assign the `cam_img.Source` property in each timer tick. 
Please make sure you're setting the `cam_img.Source` in the **UI thread**, otherwise you'll get an `InvalidOperationException` says something like:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

## Question 1:

If your `imageStream` contains the data, and you prefer the `MemoryStream`,
then you should call `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` to move the position back before you call the `BitmapFrame.Create`.

Your current code will cause an exception when creating the `BitmapFrame`, and the exception is caught, so that's why the `cam_img.Source` is never set, and was still the default 'null' value.

Comment: I answered, it is mistake, im talking about cam_img.source , not img_cam.

Comment: try `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` I think it is because your `stream.Position` is at the end of the file after the `imageStream.CopyTo(stream);`